# How to create a common api url which can be used in all components for all ajax post and get requests without using axios in vue3?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, service, base-url

How to get the prefix 'https://myapp/' stored at one place for all the requests

```
$.get({
    url : 'https://myapp/' + 'dashboard/',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        date: fromDate,
    }),
    success: function(response){
        console.log("response----------",response)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

config.js

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://myapp/';
```

then

```
import {API_BASE_URL} from './config.js';

$.get({
    url : API_BASE_URL + 'dashboard/',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        date: fromDate,
    }),
    success: function(response){
        console.log("response----------",response)
    }
});
```